# Interview answer

Tags: verbs, phrasal-verbs

Dears,

Could you please help with the sentence below, which phrasal verb and verb to use?

My goal at this point is to capitalize upon/ on new opportunities for career development, looking for/ searching/ searching for exciting new challenges.

Thank you so much !

Comment: Welcome to the site. We try to answer specific questions that you have first tried to research for yourself. We do not provide a proof-reading service. Can you explain why you have difficulty choosing from your alternatives? I add that as a matter of personal opinion I am not enthusiastic about the idea of "capitalizing on opportunities". It sounds like business jargon and if I interviewed you I would ask some hard questions to encourage you to express what you really mean by that phrase.

Comment: Anton, thank you for your answer. I would like to sound as a native English speaker and at the same time to give the impression that I could change careers successfully.

Comment: The hard truth is that no interviewer cares for a candidate's personal goals. They care how closely they match what's needed in the job. Native speakers, too, use empty words like the ones you found. Try to find honest reasons that you want the job you are interviewing for specifically.